# New Portable Hard Disk

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I've just bought a portable 2TB TOSHIBA HD that I wanted to use for back-ups.
I wanted to know if there are some things one should do when plugging it in for the first time (like see if it works properly, formatting it) and especially HOW to do those things.

I've looked into the specs of my HD and this are some info I believe to be important:

```
File system: NTFS (MS Windows)

-System Requirements: Windows® 10 / Windows 8.1 / Windows® 7
    CPU with 750 MHz or faster, 10 MB system hard disk space,
    256 MB system memory, one free port of USB 3.0 or USB 2.0
```

I have a dual-boot system on my pc (windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 17.04) so I can choose which OS to plug it in, you tell me whats best.

I'm a beginner, so please be patient, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use it for backing up both your Ubuntu and Windows systems, or are you going to use it just for backing up what you have on your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: I would like to back up both Ubuntu and Windows systems on it and - I don't know if It's possible - but I'd also like to put in single files. I was going to ask how to do that in another question actually. Right now I just want to make sure the HD is properly set up.

Comment: Yes you can store any files on it :-) And you can check it in Windows (check that a NTFS file system is working correctly in Windows.)

Comment: Please do not ask new questions within the same question/answer thread. It is much better to start with a **new question** about backup with a good descriptive title. Otherwise people will not realize that there is a new question. They will see that the question is already answered and the answer accepted as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current file system, NTFS, is good because it can be accessed for reading and writing from both Ubuntu and Windows. This means that you can use it from both operating systems for backups.

I think you can start using it directly without tampering with partitions and file systems.

Edit:

One of the first things would be to check the drive in Windows (check that the NTFS file system is working correctly in Windows.)

Then try to read and write some small file in both operating systems. Come back with questions in comments (or if more details by editing your original question).

Comment: ok so I've tried to read and write some files in both operating systems and the HD works fine. Thanks. I think now I'll edit my question to know about OS back up.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Good luck with your new question about backup :-) You can start by searching the internet for 'askubuntu backup' without quotes and look at the questions and answers that you find that way, and after that focus on your particular case.